# libxmljs installation : /bin/sh: 1: node: not found

Tags: libxml-js

I am trying to install libxmljs on Ubuntu Server 12

I ran the following command

```
sudo npm install libxmljs
```

and i get the following error.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/libxmljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/libxmljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/1.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan/1.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings/1.1.1

> libxmljs@0.10.0 install /home/xxx/node_modules/libxmljs
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/sysadmin/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and could fix it with. Probably the binary name changed from nodejs to node in a more recent version.

`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node`